# ¿Cómo crear una diana con el abecedario?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, bucle-for

Estoy atascado en un programa que debe mostrar una diana de letras.

Con entrar un entero número de letras, el usuario recibe tal diana. Ya yo he hecho el programa, pero no logro hacerlo dinámicamente.
Mi error está en las filas 4, 5, 6 en la letra "e", que no sigue el patrón de las letras anteriores, las cuales forman un anillo. Mi programa es dinámico hasta 5 letras entradas pero no más.

Condición: `1 <= num_letras <= 26`

**Ejemplo de entrada**:

> 6

**Salida**:

```
aaaaaaaaaaa

abbbbbbbbba

abcccccccba

abcdddddcba

abcdeeedcba

abcdeeedcba

abcdeeedcba

abcdddddcba

abcccccccba

abbbbbbbbba

aaaaaaaaaaa
```

**Este es mi programa**:

```
num_letras = int(input("Entrar número de letras: ")) * 2 - 1

for fil in range(num_letras):
   for col in range(num_letras):

      if fil == 0 or fil == (num_letras - 1) or col == 0 or col == (num_letras - 1):
         print(chr(97), end="")

      if (fil == 1 or fil == (num_letras - 2)) and 1 <= col < (num_letras - 1) or (2 <= fil <= (num_letras - 2) and (col == 1 or col == (num_letras - 2))):
         print(chr(98), end="")

      if (fil == 2 or fil == (num_letras - 3)) and 2 <= col < (num_letras - 2) or (3 <= fil <= (num_letras - 3) and (col == 2 or col == (num_letras - 3))):
         print(chr(99), end="")

      if (fil == 3 or fil == (num_letras - 4)) and 3 <= col < (num_letras - 3) or (4 <= fil <= (num_letras - 4) and (col == 3 or col == (num_letras - 4))):
         print(chr(100), end="")

      if (fil == 4 or fil == (num_letras - 5)) and 4 <= col < (num_letras - 4) or (4 <= fil <= (num_letras - 5) and (4 <= col <= (num_letras - 5))):
         print(chr(101), end="")
   print()
```

Comment: Hola Yurniel. ¿Puedes explicar la salida actual de tu programa y el error o problema concreto?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para completar tu pregunta con información adicional. Un saludo!

Comment: Mi error está en las filas 4, 5, 6 en la letra e, que no sigue el patrón de las letras anteriores, las cuales forman un anillo. Mi programa es dinámico hasta 5 letras entradas pero no más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, la programación tiene como objetivo en crear una forma de resolver un problema pero que se adapte dinamicamente a una situación. O sea, no se deben crear estructuras definidas para cuando n=4 (por ejemplo), si no que funcione para todos los casos siempre y cuando respeten ciertos márgenes de entrada.

Y con el problema en sí, no entiendo bien los requerimientos para hacer este código, si la generación de cada resultado hay que hacerla dentro de los ciclos `for`, o si se valen otras técnicas como acumulación en listas, reversión de cadenas e impresión inversa.
Posiblemente haya una forma más eficiente de hacer esto, pero fue lo que se me ocurrió.

En el código que propongo, con los ciclos `for` se generan la secuencia ascendente de la izquierda de la cadena (`for j`) y luego más abajo (en el `for i`) se generan las repeticiones que siguen después de la secuencia inicial.
La secuencia ascendente se usa para generar la secuencia descendente invirtiéndola.
Luego se almacenan en una lista los valores de la secuencia ascendente + los caracteres repetidos + la secuencia descendente.

Por último se imprime la lista, de forma ascendente y luego de forma descendente sin repetir el último valor.

```
num_entrada = int(input('Num Letras: '))
if (num_entrada < 1) and (num_entrada > 26):
    # Si los datos de entrada no estan dentro del rango
    exit()

num_letras =  num_entrada * 2 - 1

acumulador = []

for i in range(1, num_entrada+1):
    str_ascendente = ''
    character = 97
    for j in range(i):
        str_ascendente += chr(character)
        character += 1
    num_repeticiones = num_letras - i*2
    str_repetido = chr(character - 1) * num_repeticiones # Se genera las letras repetidas consecutivas
    str_reverso = str_ascendente[::-1] # Se invierte el string con secuencia ascendente
    if(str_repetido == ''):
        # Si se llegó a la secuencia del medio, donde solo hay un caracter diferente en todo el centro,
        # eliminarlo en el str_reverso para que no se repita.
        str_reverso = str_reverso[1:]
    elemento_procesado = str_ascendente + str_repetido + str_reverso
    acumulador.append(elemento_procesado) # Se acumula cada elemento en una lista

# La lista esta generada pero solo en forma "ascendente", ahora imprimirla en orden y luego en orden inverso
# Esto también se podría hacer con 2 ciclos for, solo que uno con la secuencia invertida.
len_list = len(acumulador)
indice = 0
while(indice < len_list*2):
    if indice < len_list:
        # Si el no se ha llegado al final de los elementos, imprimir en orden
        print(acumulador[indice])
    elif indice == len_list:
        # Si llegó al final de la lista, no imprimir nada para que no se repita el valor central
        pass
    else:
        # Si el indice ha sobrepasado al final de la lista, imprimir en orden descendente
        print(acumulador[len_list*2 - indice - 1])
    indice += 1
```

Comment: Hola, @aeportugal. Sin duda alguna tu proposición de programa resuelve mi problema. La cuestión ahora es que yo comprenda el porqué de cada sentencia teniendo en cuenta que soy principiante en el mundo de la programación.